# Authenticate by source address with CouchDB

Tags: authentication, couchdb

Is it possible to set up CouchDB to authenticate users (or authorize them differently) based on which IP address the request originated instead of some secret like a password? I'm looking for a solution that can be implemented by the build-in web server of CouchDB without an additional HTTP proxy.

My use case is that I want to allow an application running on the same machine as the CouchDB server full access to all databases while clients and other CouchDB instances should only be allowed to read and write normal (non-design) documents.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I'm looking at something similar

Comment: @tier1 Sadly, no. I would have added an answer if I did. Especially after the countless times Google directed me to an answer I've written myself but have forgotten about. ;-)